# Lazy loading with primefaces mobile

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I am actually a newbie and I have a newbie question , 
Is it possible to use primefaces mobile for lazy data loading without having to use jQuery or any other stuff?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with Primefaces 5:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/mobile/lazyload.jsf